# Run Qt QProcess independently on the OS

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qprocess, multiplatform

I am developing an application on QT in C++ and I learned recently how to use it, therefore I am still not totally confident. I am struggling with this: I am developing on Linux but I would like to make it work also on Windows. The C++ code calls a Python script (passing some arguments to it), and to achieve my aim I am using

`QDir::separator()`

to separate the folders names(the arguments list contains some paths), and this should be useful to my purpose, because it will use automatically / for Linux and \ on Windows (correct me if I am wrong).

The code looks like this:

```
python_path= my_python_path/python;
script_path=../script.py;


QStringList arguments;
arguments << QString(script_path);
arguments << QString(arg1);
arguments << QString(arg2);


QProcess *p = new QProcess( this );

if (p){

  p->start(python_path,arguments);
}
```

Now my problem: on Windows I should use:

```
 python_path= my_python_path/python.exe;
```

instead of:

```
 python_path= my_python_path/python;
```

How to treat this multi platform development on QT? Detect the system and use a if? Or is there some better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Q_OS macros. Something like that should works (not tested):

```
#if defined Q_OS_WIN
QString python_path = "my_python_path/python.exe";
#else
QString python_path = "my_python_path/python";
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!